# How can I compare the contents of a byte register with "\n" to realise when the line changed in Assembly x86_64 at&t?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, string-comparison, att

I am trying to compare two strings, and when a mismatch letter 
occurs then I have to print the line of the mismatch of both strings.

```
(e.g. string1: "Test\ntest" string2: "Tost\ntistss", it must print 1, 
1 in the first mismatch ("o"), 2 2 in the second mismatch, 2 2 as well 
in the third mismatch etc etc)
```

My question is: How can I compare a value with "\n"? Appreciate any 
     help. I cannot post my code since the only help that I want is the 
     way of comparing with "\n" to realise the end of line, hence to 
     increment the index and print it.

Comment: Do you mean: `cmp $'\n', %al`?

Comment: Yeah dude, thank you.

Comment: In *NIX world (guessing it froom at&t syntax usage) the newline has value `10`. But writing it in source as `\n` is safer, i.e. Martin's suggestion is perfect. You just should understand, that it's simple 8 bit integer value, just like any other ASCII character, i.e. the machine code produced is: `cmp $10,%al`  (may be `cmp $13,%al` on old Mac OS  and on windows/DOS you would have to catch two bytes: 13, 10 = `"\r\n"`).